# Changing storage engine to InnoDb from MyIsam is dropping records from table

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

Currently our Database all tables are using MyIsam as a storage engine. We tried changing storage engine of our mysql tables from MyISAM to InnoDB from PHPMyAdmin operations tab. However during the change table records are dropped. So what can be the possible factor causing this problem.

**This is what we tried:**

We converted `test_user` table which was having storage engine `MyIsam` and was having total records 11k. When we converted it into `InnoDB` the records droped to 9k. This happened for many tables. Not sure what we are doign wrong.

Comment: Please add table definition and if you can examples of the rows droppped. do you have foreign keys defined in the myisam tables?

Comment: A liitle research indicates it may not be as simple as just altering http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: @P.Salmon some tables have FKs but not all of them have FK. Let me share table definition.

Comment: @P.Salmon a table definition https://pastecode.xyz/view/raw/a00f3fc1

Comment: I cannot access that site.

Comment: @P.Salmon it's working fine BTW here is the table @ https://www.paste.org/flat/104794

Comment: Did you ask this somewhere else?  And I explained that `EXPLAIN` does not provide exact Row counts for InnoDB?